# Copper sulphate solution dissolves iron nail?

Tags: solutions

I tried an experiment of the Galvanic series and put three iron nails (slightly rusty, but brushed) into a copper sulphate solution and waited a few days until the nails get coated with copper.

Strangely something entirely different happened. The nails got almost dissolved, yet quite a bunch of residue added up.

I was not expecting this to happen. Could someone tell me what I did wrong?
Thank you

[image: Dissolved nail [1]]

Comment: Displacement reaction occurred, but the copper would not automatically stick to the iron. I reckon that electroplating is needed to make them stick.

Comment: I got the instruction from that German page: http://netexperimente.de/chemie/118.html - but now did some research in the English parts of chemistry-pages. So far I couldn't find any information anything else would be required to make the reaction work (for example: https://schoollabs.wordpress.com/2013/02/23/iron-nails-copper-sulphate/ )

Comment: Well, the video in the page is curious... it worked in the video?

Comment: @bon - which of my writings would you like to have formatted?

Comment: None in particular. I'm just putting it there for future reference.

Comment: @KennyLau: The video and the page use a different time frame than I did. They mention "short time" and in the video 2h. I used _days_ as I had been curious what would happen. The more the result was unexpected.